# getElementBy to get Value JS

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

Can someone help pull the value with "3355"?

```
<form action="http://www.ebest.cl/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5lYmVzdC5jbC9hdWRpZm9ub3MtYWx0YS1maWRlbGlkYWQtaG91c2Utb2YtbWFybGV5LXJldm9sdXRpb24uaHRtbD9fX19TSUQ9VQ,,/product/3355/form_key/c2b66ca036853b1a/" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form">
    <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="c2b66ca036853b1a" />
    <div class="no-display">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="3355" />
        <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
    </div>
```

Which getElementBy function would I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.querySelector(".no-display > input[name=product]").value;
```

or more specific:

```
document.querySelector("#product_addtocart_form .no-display > input[name=product]").value;
```

Comment: Can I create a function in google tag manager using: 
var prodID = document.querySelector(".no-display > input[name=product]").value;

return prodID;